# Yubikey PGP migration

Tags: openpgp, yubikey

I am currently using a Yubikey 4 with my PGP subkeys on it.
My mainkey is stored within Kleopatra.

As I am planning to move over to a new Yubikey 5 I have asked myself if it is possible to still be able to decrypt emails with my new pair of subkeys generated for the new Yubikey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important question **is how you generated your PGP key and subkeys**.

As explained in the [docs](https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000006420-using-your-yubikey-with-openpgp) there are two ways:

- Generating Keys externally from the YubiKey (Recommended)
- Generating Your PGP Key directly on Your YubiKey

The first approach is recommended. You can use a live distro such as Tails to generate your keys on an airgapped (without networking) computer. Then you make **backups** of your keys to removable storage like a USB key or a hard drive, that you keep in a secure place.

The other option is to generate the keys directly on the device. This is very secure but the major drawback is that you cannot backup the keys. If you lose or destroy the device you lose your keys. With this approach, migration is not possible. This option should be avoided unless you know that your key is going to have a limited shelf life.

So if you chose option #1, it is quite easy. You don't need the old YubiKey. Start your live distro, reimport your private keys from the external storage, and you write them to the new YubiKey with the `keytocard` command.

To answer the question: in order to retain access to your mails you must keep the current key (and subkeys). But the hardware itself does not have to stay the same, it could be another YubiKey or a smart card as long as you have that external backup.

If you really must change your PGP key: in theory you could decrypt files and reencrypt them with a new key,  But with E-mails this is complicated. They are probably stored in a mbox or pst file. Even if they are available as standalone files (on an IMAP server for instance), it's not the whole file that is encrypted but the mail body. The headers are still in clear. AFAIK PGP cannot just decrypt the encrypted part while keeping the rest of the file intact. There is no easy solution I'm afraid.

---

However, I did a test with Thunderbird. I chose an encrypted message, selected the whole message source (Ctrl-U) and copied it to a file. Then using `gpg -d <the file>` from the command line I was able to read the mail after entering the passphrase. But you don't have the headers and all that. What you get is a stripped-down version. It's not something that you could reinject to the mbox file for instance.

Comment: Hello Anonymous, I have done a mixture of creating keys.

Mainkey & encryption subkey withing Kleopatra on Windows
Authentication & verification on Yubikey directly.

I guess the most important key (encryption and main) are good to go for my new key.

Comment: Maybe there is hope. Can you add the output of `gpg2 --expert --list-secret-keys your_key` to your question, where `your_key` is your key ID or associated E-mail ? This should list your **subkeys** and whether they are *stored externally* (indicated by the `>` sign). You probably have 3 subkeys: signing (S), encryption (E) and authentication (A). For more security all subkeys should reside on the Yubikey though. Keeping the primary (certification) key on your PC somewhat defeats the purpose of the Yubikey.

Comment: All my subkeys are stored on Yubikey indicated with the `>` sign.
Might it work to revoke those keys afterwards and create new keys which I put on my new Yubikey?

Regarding the primary key for certification: I know that this storing on the pc is not the best solution but I will keep it until I have my new Yubikey.
But I already stored it on an encrypted container which I put on an external drive.

Comment: Creating new keys will not help. You need the current keys to read your mails. Sounds like you are out of luck here. The important lesson is, have backups of your keys and for this you have to generate them externally. You can still get a new Yubikey and generate new keys that you will use from now on. But in order to access past E-mails you will need the old device. If you have some important mails, you could archive the plain text contents after decryption. Then backup or re-encrypt.

Comment: Okay thanks - so the best approach would be:
1) Generate mainkey, generate all subkeys externally.
2) Backup everything on an encrypted external media.
3) Subkeys `keytocard` on Yubikey

Is that right?

Comment: That's the idea. I would even make more than one backup and store the media in different places. Being paranoid, I generate keys on a live distro (Tails), offline and without network connection. The aim is not to leave any forensic trace of the subkeys on hard drive or under supervision of an operating system that may be compromised (think trojan).

Comment: Whats the better way to export: Using a gpg command like `gpg --export-secret-key' (need to see the right command at the manual) or copy/paste the gpg folder?

Comment: I'd rather export the single key. You could do both to be sure. What is important is to **test your backup** and verify that you can fully reimport the private key and all the associated subkeys, to be able to write them to a new device if necessary. There is nothing more tragic than untested, useless backups. Always test this before you move the keys to the hardware.

Comment: Yeah, I know that thing regarding backup and testing - doing this on my servers as well. Backup and verify that I can restore the data.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay so I received my new Yubikey today on configured it the way you described it: I have exported the main key and each single subkey before I put the subkeys to the Yubikey + copied the whole folder to an encrypted container.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the key outside Yubikey, just import them using gpg --edit-card and keytocard. If the keys are only available in Yubikey, they can't be exported.